# An error occurred while reading the Excel: java.io.IOException: /tmp/poifiles/poi-ooxml--490226367.tmp (No such file or directory)

Tags: coldfusion-10

I used cfspreadsheet for the first time and I was happy with it. I just want to show the spread sheet using action="read" and nothing else. So I used:

```
        <CFSET theDir = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath())>
        <CFSET MyReportPath = "#Trim(theDir)#Report/Rptissues/MyReport
                                                          /Report.xlsx">

        <cfspreadsheet action = "read"
                       src="#Trim(MyReportPath)#"
                       query="excelquery"
                       sheet="1"
                       columns="1,2,3,4,5"
                       excludeHeaderRow="TRUE"></cfspreadsheet>
```

I was able to see the query, but that was last month. Today when I ran it I got:

```
 An error occurred while reading the Excel: java.io.IOException:    
 /tmp/poifiles/poi-ooxml--490226367.tmp (No such file or directory).

 The error occurred in /home/space/users/www/webdocsec
 /advisoryindex.cfm: line 174
 Called from /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/index.cfm: line 19
 Called from /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/advisoryindex.cfm: line 174
 Called from /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/index.cfm: line 19
    172 : src="#Trim(MyReportPath)#"
    173 : query="excelquery"
    174 : excludeHeaderRow="TRUE"></cfspreadsheet>
    175 :
```

I checked the path, it is correct. I checked the excel file, it is still there and I can't find posting anywhere with similar error.

Comment: Well, does `/tmp/poifiles/poi-ooxml--490226367.tmp` exist? Does the `/tmp/poifiles` directory, and if does it have the right permissions? Maybe the machine has rebooted since it last worked and /tmp was cleaned in the process.

Comment: You are correct! it is not permisison issue but /tmp was cleaned somehow. Thank you!!!